# Seeking short story title, a boy refuses to remove his helmet, story ends while he is riding a train

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A boy refuses to remove his helmet during his everyday life, (I think) due to a constant fear of nuclear annihilation. I believe the protagonist is his father (perhaps a scientist, maybe one whose work is related to nuclear energy or weapons). What I recall clearly is that **the story ends while the boy is riding a subway train, and he looks up to see that everyone in the train has also put on helmets of their own to make him feel less afraid.**

I read the story when I was very young in 1989 (in English). I believe the story could have been published any time between 1930 - 1970.

I cannot recall any details of the book it was published in, and I cannot find any story descriptions that resemble this after searching all of the relevant keywords online.

Comment: I may be corrected here, but you may want to move this to the Literature SE, as it's pretty close to actual life.

Comment: I fail to see what this story (about a small paranoid boy) has to do with science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots This sounds fairly familiar to Philip K. Dick story ["Foster, you're dead!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foster,_You%27re_Dead!), which would be  on-topic here. If so, I can't see why this one is not also not on topic.

Comment: @Yasskier Thanks for the reply. I just looked up the PKD story you mentioned - the story I'm trying to identify was very similar in thematic content but definitely ended with the son riding a train wearing a helmet. I'm fairly certain the story was science fiction (near future setting) but again I read it when I was fairly young.